# Plex errors on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: plex

I installed Plex media server onto my jaunty server about a year ago and than poof it now won't work. I did a status on the service and I get these error lines:

```
● plexmediaserver.service - Plex Media Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/plexmediaserver.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2023-12-01 22:29:16 PST; 4s ago
    Process: 6864 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c /usr/bin/test -d "${PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_APPLICATION_SUPPORT_DIR}" || /bin/mkd>
    Process: 6866 ExecStart=/bin/sh -c  export PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_INFO_VENDOR="$(grep ^NAME= /etc/os-release | awk -F=>
   Main PID: 6866 (code=exited, status=127)
        CPU: 14ms

Dec 01 22:29:16 Starfleet systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Dec 01 22:29:16 Starfleet systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Dec 01 22:29:16 Starfleet systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Dec 01 22:29:16 Starfleet systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 01 22:29:21 Starfleet systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Dec 01 22:29:21 Starfleet systemd[1]: Stopped Plex Media Server.
Dec 01 22:29:21 Starfleet systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Dec 01 22:29:21 Starfleet systemd[1]: plexmediaserver.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 01 22:29:21 Starfleet systemd[1]: Failed to start Plex Media Server.
```

1. I have uninstalled remove the directory and reinstall several times.
2. I have `chown` the directory
3. I have also `chmod -R 777` the directory

I have yet to figure out the solution, has anyone found a way to fix this I would appreciate it very much.

UPDATE 1:
Sorry I did not respond sooner but I am more busy during the week than the weekend.

but I installed Plex with through the following commands:

```
> echo deb https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb public main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/plexmediaserver.list
> curl https://downloads.plex.tv/plex-keys/PlexSign.key | sudo apt-key add -
> sudo apt update
> sudo apt install plexmediaserver
```

This was recommended by a Reddit post that showed how to install Plex. Another post said that they were able to fix this error by changing permissions/privileges of the

```
/usr/lib/plexmediaserver
```

folder. I wanted to try everything before posting on a forum.

I tried the following command:

```
/bin/sh -c  export PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_INFO_VENDOR="$(grep ^NAME= /etc/os-release | awk -F
```

and I could not find it, I think that might be the problem.

Comment: Can you edit your question with some additional details? How did you install Plex? What directory you are talking about? Add the full `chown` and `chmod` commands. What do you have in `/var/lib/plexmediaserver/Library/Application Support/Plex Media Server/Logs/Plex Media Server.log`

Comment: Note that error 127 usually means that the process tried to execute a command and couldn't find it...which is probably not going to be fixed my mucking with file permissions.

Comment: `/bin/sh -c  export PLEX_MEDIA_SERVER_INFO_VENDOR="$(grep ^NAME= /etc/os-release | awk -F=>`  is not working. check for the whole command and execute on command line to see if it shows more on the issue

Comment: I couldn't find that service, is that the problem?

Comment: here's the crash log:

Dec 15, 2023 22:49:51: Failed to initialize logging: Error parsing file at "/var/lib/plexmediaserver/Library/Application Support/Plex Media Server/Preferences.xml"

Comment: I am having the exact same issue and it started about the same time. I have tried everything i know. Nothing. I am going to try to install an older version of plex. If that does not work then ill go back ubuntu 18. I have had nothing but issues with ubuntu 20.04. Thanks

Comment: I downloaded the latest stable version to date, then use this and it worked. If yours differs then replace the alphanumeric's to suit.                                                        (sudo wget https://downloads.plex.tv/plex-media-server-new/1.32.8.7639-fb6452ebf/debin/plexmediaserver_1.32.8.7639-fb6452ebf_amd64.deb)                                    This is the distribution,Ubuntu (16.04+) / Debian (8+) - Intel/AMD 64-bit. Once done, i used (systemctl status plexmediaserver) to check to see if it is running, and it was working great. Thanks and hope this helps.